# How does the diffusion of a finite volume method with a WENO scheme compare with that of spectral methods?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, numerics, finite-volume, spectral-method

I know that, in general, finite volume (FV) methods are more (numerically) diffusive than spectral methods. However, I can't find any information on how the advection scheme changes that.

For example, WENO schemes are supposed to decrease numerical diffusion and presumably would get numerical diffusion of FV methods closer to that of spectral methods. But how much so? Is is much better than using an upwind scheme?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is quite general and result may change regarding the model you are looking at. For example, spectral methods (other than finite element method) may converge very slowly for solutions including discontinuities. The FV upwind scheme, may in some cases, exhibit those discontinuities very accurately and with a faster convergence. However, again, it depends on the model you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the diffusion dispersion relations:

- [Upwind, ENO, WENO](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999118306703), see Fig. 2
- [DG, CG](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999115008256?via%3Dihub), see Fig. 15

Regards